# Non Greedy Regex from Left

Tags: regex, non-greedy

I have string like this:

> \24s904dS\24sr4d2\24**x\\y\\12z:234F\\3dRl**\24o980\24

I want to match the bold part only:

```
x\\y\\12z:234F\\3dRl
```

I can take care the non-greedy for right part with this regex:

```
\\24(.*:.*?)\\24
```

But still can't find out how to deal with non-greedy for left part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this **negative lookahead** based regex:

```
\\24((?:.(?!\\24))*:.*?)\\24
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sI2bL6/1)

Important part is this lookahead based regex pattern `(?:.(?!\\24))*`, which means match a character if `\24` is not followed. That essentially makes sure **most adjacent left** `\24` is matched.

**Output Match:**

```
x\\y\\12z:234F\\3dRl
```

Comment: `?:` is actually a non-capturing group.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks a lot. Now I'm confused which answer that I should choose between alpha bravo's and yours. I ended up using alpha bravo's answer anyway, but still, your answer is also correct.

Comment: You can understand the difference between 2 approaches with 2 demos. [My approach: Demo1](https://regex101.com/r/sI2bL6/2) and [bravo's approach: Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/sI2bL6/3). You can clearly see in my regex you can capture both the matches enclosed by `\24` on either side but not in the other approach.

Answer (score 4):

modify your pattern as follows

```
.*\\24(.*:.*?)\\24
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than modifying the greediness, it's better to just write a more-precise regex:

```
\\24([a-zA-Z0-9]+:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\24
```

(It's relatively rare that non-greedy modifiers are really the best approach to a problem.)

Comment: It can has "\\" in the string as well (I have edited my question).